# Moving in world space while looking at the mouse position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move the player using the WASD keys while it always looking at the mouse position.
My problem is the W key will always move the player toward the mouse position while i want it to keep moving using the world space.
This is the code for moving the player.

```c#
private void FixedUpdate()
{ 
    MovementHandler();
    RotationHandler();
}

void MovementHandler()
{
    float hInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    float speed = Input.GetButton("Run") ? runSpeed : walkSpeed;

    Vector3 hMovement = characterController.isGrounded == true ? transform.forward * vInput : Vector3.zero;
    Vector3 vMovement = characterController.isGrounded == true ? transform.right * hInput : Vector3.zero;

    characterController.SimpleMove(Vector3.ClampMagnitude(hMovement +    vMovement, 1) * speed);
}

void RotationHandler()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, 100, groundMask))
    {
        transform.LookAt(hit.point);
    }
}
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the objects local space [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) and [`transform.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html)

If you rather wanted world space axis for the movement I guess you should rather use [`Vector3.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html) and [`Vector3.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html)

```c#
var hMovement = characterController.isGrounded ? Vector3.forward * vInput : Vector3.zero;
var vMovement = characterController.isGrounded ? Vector3.right * hInput : Vector3.zero;
```

---

You should in general use [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) for frame based movements and user interactions!

[`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) should only be used for stuff related to the Physics (like e.g. RigidBody movement and forces).

```c#
private void Update()
{ 
    MovementHandler();
    RotationHandler();
}
```

Comment: that worked but its really buggy, moving the mouse quickly or moving it by the player  made him go up flying, do you suggest any other solution? thanks

Comment: @Ayhem Did that problem already occur when you were using the code you show in the question?

Comment: @Ruzihm nope I think you misinterpret the API ;) It says `Speed is in units/s` .. meaning `speed` is **supposed** to be passed in in units/seconds ... but OP didn't do this since he didn't multiply by `Time.deltaTime` so currently it is a framerate dependent movement with `Vector3.forward * vInput` per frame.

Comment: @Ruzihm You are partially right. I have not to multiply but to devide. If this is called every frame (what it should be) afaik `x` is in `units/frame`. deltaTime is in `frame/second` so `x / deltaTime` should be in `units/frame * frame/second` = `units/second` right? A bit confused here :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197171/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-derhugo).

Comment: @derHugo changing to update() from FixedUpdate() kind of fixed the problem! its not easy to make the player fly like it used to.
One question though, like you said FixedUpdate is related to physics, and as far as i know the CharacterController supposed to work with physics since it take care of collisions and gravity, should it not be a better option then using Update() in my case? thanks a lot and sorry for the late response!